# each do jquery não encontra "TR" adicionada dinamicamente a tabela

Tags: jquery, html

Olá, possuo uma tabela onde a primeira TR dela é fixa contendo alguns inputs para pesquisar

```
Assunto | Data   | Categoria
input1  | input2 | input3
item1   | item 1 | item 1
```

Onde este item 1 é adicionado dinamicamente conforme o resultado da pesquisa do input, meu código atual:

```
$(document).on("keyup", "input", function(){
    var tipo = $(this).attr("name");
    var text = $(this).val();
    var obj = {}
    obj[tipo] = text;
    $.ajax({
        url: "minhaurl",
        data: obj,
        type: "POST",
        success: function(result){
            $('table > tbody > tr').not('#resident').each(function() {
                $(this).remove();
            });

            $("#meusLec").append(result);
        }
    });
});
```

Ele funciona corretamente, mas apenas na primeira pesquisa, na segunda onde os itens são adicionados dinamicamente, o jquery não percorre o each e não esvazia a tabela com os novos resultados

Answer (score 0):

Acredito que entendi o que precisa fazer. A ideia é um buscador por colunas na tabela. Caso esteja errado me corrija.

Para fazer esta funcionalidade, os campos `<input/>` serão no `<thead>`, não no `<tbody>`. Outra coisa. Não há a necessidade de fazer uma nova requisição para popular a tabela a cada `keyup` do usuário. Ao menos que o processamento seja *server-side*. Enfim, vamos lá:

O exemplo funcional tem [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/djalmamanfrin/rrL6begm/7/)

Esta é a **Estrutura `HTML`**:

```
<table id="example">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
    <tr id="tr-search">
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tfoot>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Position</th>
      <th>Office</th>
    </tr>
  </tfoot>
  <tbody>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="name">Tiger Nixon</td>
      <td class="position">System Architect</td>
      <td class="office">Edinburgh</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="name">Garrett Winters</td>
      <td class="position">Accountant</td>
      <td class="office">Tokyo</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="name">Ashton Cox</td>
      <td class="position">Junior Technical Author</td>
      <td class="office">San Francisco</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="row">
      <td class="name">Cedric Kelly</td>
      <td class="position">Senior Javascript Developer</td>
      <td class="office">Edinburgh</td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

**Estrutura `CSS`**

```
.remove {
  display: none;
}
```

**Estrutura `JavaScript`**

```
$('#example thead th').each( function () {
  var title = $(this).text();
  $('#tr-search').append( '<td><input type="text" class="inputs-search" name="'+title.toLowerCase()+'" placeholder="Looking for '+title.toLowerCase()+'"/></td>');
});

$('.inputs-search').on('keyup', function(){
    var search = $(this).val();
    var column = $(this).attr("name");
  var target = '.row .' + column;
  var match = new RegExp(search, "i"); 

  $(target).each(function(){
        if (!match.test($(this).text())) {
        $(this).closest('tr').addClass('remove');
      } else {
        $(this).closest('tr').removeClass('remove');
      }
  });
});
```

Para funcionar, basta popular a tabela do banco conforme está fazendo. Uma dica, tudo isso que foi desenvolvido na unha, poderia ter sido facilmente desenvolvido usando o *plugin* do *JQuery* [datatables](https://datatables.net/examples/index). Que por acaso, já dispõem dessa funcionalidade prontinha.

Fiz este exemplo para ilustrar [aqui](https://jsfiddle.net/djalmamanfrin/cm0hLt0f/). Qualquer dúvida, só comentar.

Comment: Então, obrigado pela resposta, mas eu realmente preciso buscar no servidor, o resultado dessa tabela está em constante atualização, e sempre preciso do valor atual dela. No meu primeiro script era apenas um teste, agora só faço a requisição após o usuário terminar de digitar.

Comment: O _datatables_ já tem uma funcionalidade _server-side_ [aqui](https://datatables.net/examples/server_side/simple.html). Sua necessidada é fazer isso usando apenas _JQuery_?